# class path resource [io/axoniq/axonserver/config/MetricsConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

Am trying to create a microservice using spring boot and axon framework to achieve CQRS and Event sourcing. Am getting the FileNotFoundException when I run the Application. I couldn't find any solution on internet. Can someone guide me to the resolution? Let me know if I need to add any details.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read meta-data for class io.axoniq.axonserver.config.MetricsConfiguration
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:237) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:208) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.access$000(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:154) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.lambda$getInPriorityOrder$0(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:63) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.getInPriorityOrder(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:62) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.sortAutoConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:468) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:453) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:882) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at com.estocks.estockscommandservice.EstocksCommandServiceApplication.main(EstocksCommandServiceApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [io/axoniq/axonserver/config/MetricsConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:55) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter$AutoConfigurationClass.getAnnotationMetadata(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:233) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
... 27 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.7</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>axon-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're hitting a versioning issue here, @sai.
As far as I know, the latest `axon-bom` you can use is 4.5.12, not 4.5.8 which you're using.

Furthermore, Axon Framework isn't built with Spring Boot 2.6.7 at the moment.
I recall having some wiring predicaments when I paired the latest Spring Boot with Axon's Reactor extension (Project Reactor introduced some breaking changes, sadly enough). This required me to move back to 2.6.6.

So, concluding, please try out a combination of `axon-bom` 4.5.12 and `spring-boot-starter-parent` 2.6.6!

Comment: thanks for response, @Steven. I tried updating the versions. But still couldn't resolve the issue. Any idea on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you taken a look through the dependency tree of your project? I am still guessing there might be something amiss with different versions... With the dependency tree you should be able to see if you're consistently using the same version of your dependencies.

Comment: You can also try to setup a new project using the AxonIQ Initializr... I guess the dependencies and the simple setup should work out of the box! https://start.axoniq.io/

Comment: thanks @steven, I was able to fix the issue by creating a totally new project with the same versions mentioned in question and excluding project reactor. A question out of context, is there a way to contact your team(Axon) for live support on some queries around axon-kafka?

Comment: @LucasCampos, thanks for response. I might try that out soon.

Comment: That's likely an option, @sai, although you'd likely move through some 'salesy' kinda guys too. Here's the contact page if you'd want to set up a conversation - https://www.axoniq.io/contact